# This code is clicking continuously and i want only once

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```
var sel=document.forms[1].children[0].children[0];
        for(var i=0;i<sel.children.length;i++)
        {
            if(!sel.children[i].innerHTML.match(/,/))
            {
                sel.selectedIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

document.getElementsByClassName('m2')[21].children[0].click();
```

The problem is that this code is clicking continuously and i want only once.

on this i want to click

```
<a href="javascript:document.frm_42.submit();">Start</a>
```

Comment: More context is required.

Comment: Can you put this in a Fiddle?  "Continuously" is a little vague.

Comment: What does the loop on the select options have to do with clicking on the anchor?

Comment: Are you calling any of this code inside an `onclick` handler?

Comment: Try jquery one() function. I am assuming that you want to make it unclickable after the after the first click